# STM32F103CBT7 dev_target_held_under_reset problem

Tags: pcb, stm32, reset

I have a PCB with the STM32F103CBT7 microprocessor. I used the ST-Link V2 with the STM32CubeProgrammer to programm it which I think worked the first time as it connected and and ended programming without any errors. However, after that I realised the board didn't work as intended and when trying to change the code I got the error dev_target_held_under_reset. I have tried many things since but nothing has worked so I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Please provide more info. Do you use SWD or JTAG? Do you have reset pin and supply connected between STLINK and your board? What settings you use? Does your MCU program disable JTAG or SWD at startup? Schematics available for review? Software source code available for review?

Comment: Between the STLINK and the board I have connected the Supply, Reset, Ground, SWDIO and SWCLK. This is the code in CubeIDE and schematic in EAGLE https://we.tl/t-CpY038CSyh

Comment: I used SWD in Normal Mode and Software Reset

Comment: Ah, so if you develop in CubeIde, can you program and debug in CubeIde?

Comment: Yes you can. You can even programm the MCU directly from the IDE however I prefer the programmer because you can see whether it is connected or not